# WPF double click edit label

Tags: c#, wpf, widget

I have a label displaying some content. When a user double clicks the label, it should enable a user to change the content.

I did some research and found that it's usually very complex to achieve this simple effect. http://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2010/10/05/making-wpf-controls-double-clickable/

But all I need is a label (or textbox) that can be editable when double clicked. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `textbox` like:

```
TextBox editLbl = new TextBox();
//add it to the controls list to display it
```

and set all properties of the label to the `textbox` like `location`, `size` etc.

Set the `keydown` event and on pressing enter, hide the `textbox` and set the value to the label.

You can also set `background color` theme same as your form window has to look like you are editing the label.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Controls` even does not exist in any context of `WPF`, maybe you thought the OP used `winforms` but not, s/he uses `wpf`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to handle some events (setting up all in XAML code is not possible):

```
//Initially set Focusable to false
textBox1.Focusable = false;
textBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

//FocusableChanged event handler for your textBox1
private void textBox1_FocusableChanged(object sender, 
                                       DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
  textBox1.Cursor = textBox1.Focusable ? Cursors.IBeam : Cursors.Arrow;
}
//MouseDoubleClick event handler for your textBox1
private void textBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
  textBox1.Focusable = true;
  textBox1.Focus();
  textBox1.CaretIndex = textBox1.Text.Length;
}
//LostFocus event handler for your textBox1
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  textBox1.Focusable = false;
}
```

Comment: I just devised some very similar code, but I'm finding the LostFocus is fired immediately after the double click event.

Answer (score 1):

if you do non MVVM you can simply do the following

- create a Grid with your label and a hidden textbox
- on label doubleclick event set textbox visibillity to visible
- bind textbox text to label
- on textbox lostfocus event set textbox visibillity to hidden

Answer (score 1):

This way works fine for me. Fixed previous answer code in this thread (LostFocus is fired immediately after the double click).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public class DoubleClickTextBoxBehaviour : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private long _timestamp;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Focusable = false;
        AssociatedObject.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

        AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick += AssociatedObjectOnMouseDoubleClick;
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += AssociatedObjectOnLostFocus;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton != MouseButton.Left)
            return;

        if (AssociatedObject.Focusable)
            return;//fix an issue of selecting all text on double click

        AssociatedObject.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
        AssociatedObject.Focusable = true;
        AssociatedObject.Focus();
        AssociatedObject.CaretIndex = AssociatedObject.Text.Length;

        _timestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var delta = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - _timestamp;
        var timesp = new TimeSpan(delta);

        if (timesp.TotalSeconds < 1)
            return;

        AssociatedObject.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        AssociatedObject.Focusable = false;
    }
}
```

Attach it to textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:DoubleClickTextBoxBehaviour />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

If errors